# doctrine one table is referenced by multiple tables, how can i get the reference record without switch

Tags: mysql, doctrine

imaging i have 3 tables, person, boy, girl

```
 table person{
     id
     ...}
 table boy{
    id,
    foreign key a_id= a.id, one to one,
    description,
    ...
}
table girl{
    id,
    foreign key a_id= a.id, one to one, 
    description,
    ...
}
```

table person can only referenced once by boy or girl. If now i get a person id, how can I quickly get the boy/girl information without trying to initiate a boy and a girl? cause my problem is i have so many tables a referenced by the table person, and the if will be too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better way is to place the table name in your person table ,, i.e add a column in your person table which have the name of table boy , girl etc.

Then you can easily refer to correct table